# Why I am getting error on numericDeriv Error in R

Tags: r, gradient, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a simple nonlinear model in R but getting an error that I do not understand

```
x = c(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0)
y = c(6085, 2351,  940,  371,  145)
fit <- nls(y ~ exp(a+b*x), start=list(a=1, b=1))
```

Why R cannot calculate numerical gradient?

Comment: your starting parameters are not a good fit to the data; `plot(x, y, pch=16); lines(x, exp(1+x))`

Comment: Try `a = 9` and `b = -2`.

Comment: ... i.e. starting coeffs from `lm(log(y) ~ x)`

Comment: @user20650 Thanks ! it helped, but at where R failed to calculate the gradient?

Comment: @Edward thanks it worked. Now i know where is the problem.